# how to set focus at specific position in Entry + xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, textbox, setfocus

my entry box has some text already.so can I set cursor focus at start of text?
how? I coudnt find any option for that.if anybody have idea.please suggest.

Comment: yes i want cusrosr focus at left side of text(starting of textbox) but it is not comming

Comment: yes i did that already.

Comment: Actually I have created demo project, When setting `txtdummy.Text="Welcome"` than focus  `txtdummy.focus()` in `OnAppearing()` focus showing in the starting of `Entry`.

Comment: in xamarin.forms?

Comment: Yes! In Xamarin.Forms shared project.

Comment: dont know not working in mine.btw. i have 1 question? in mobile app there wont be focus in load of page.as there will not keyboard open first..

once user clicks on text than keybopard will get open.so wherever he click focus will be there??

it should be like that?

Answer (score 0):

As you said

> In mobile app there wont be focus in load of page.as there will not
>   keyboard open first.. once user clicks on text than keybopard will get
>   open.so wherever he click focus will be there?

In mobile app On load focus depend on the requirement. Check out most luxurious android app *linkedIn* login page, have focus in Username `Entry` without opening keypad. If you want to avoid using custom renderers in XF than you have to do bit compromise with functionality.

Your second point true- Wherever user clicks focus would be there.

Try doing like this, First update Xamarin.Forms version to 3.1.0.697729 from nuget packages & target framework change to Oreo 8.1.

XAML file

```
<StackLayout>
<Entry x:Name="txtDummy" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

your .cs file

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        txtDummy.Text = "I am focus";
        txtDummy.Focus();
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
}
```

Look at output screenshot

[image]